# ggplotly: conflict of labels for tooltip with data of added layer

Tags: r, ggplotly

Given:

```
library(plotly)
p = ggplot(iris, aes(label=Species)) + 
  geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width))
ggplotly(p)
```

I want to add reference lines, eg:

```
a <- data.frame(ID=rep(1:3,2),Type=rep(1:3,2), Sepal.Length=rep(5:7,2), Sepal.Width=rep(c(0,5),rep(3,2)))
a
 Type Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
1  1            5           0
2  2            6           0
3  3            7           0
4  1            5           5
5  2            6           5
6  3            7           5
```

but:

```
> p <- ggplot(iris, aes(label=Species)) + 
+     geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)) +
+     geom_line(data=a, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Type, group=ID))
> ggplotly(p)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Species' not found
```

The following works (but I have to sacrifice the Species info in the tooltip):

```
p = ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_line(data=a, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, color=Type, group=ID))
ggplotly(p)
```

I want both the Species info and the Type of the reference line in the tooltip (There are often quite a lot and a legend is thus impractical).
A solution might be appending `a` to the `iris` dataframe, but I prefer to avoid that.

If I try (as suggested but including group=ID):

```
    p <- ggplot(iris, aes(label = Species)) + 
      geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_line(data = a, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Type, label = NA, group=ID))
Warning message:
In geom_line(data = a, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Type,  :
  Ignoring unknown aesthetics: label
p
ggplotly(p)
```

But both the ggplot and ggplotly look ok. I had tried this before, but the Warning message made me not try the ggplotly(p) command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code will work if you add a label to your `geom_line`, and you haven't defined ID, I have used type to get lines. Is that what you intended?

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(label = Species)) + 
     geom_point(aes(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)) +
     geom_line(data = a, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Type, label = NA))
```

Comment: I have edited the original question to add the output of your suggestion. While I consider the issue to be solved, I would like to understand: 1. Why the original error occurs. 2. Why does just adding label=NA (which according to the Warning message is actually ignored) solves the issue.

Comment: I can answer your second question: `ggplot2` does not include a `label` aesthetic. If you just look at the plot without `ggplotly`, nothing happens if you hover over your data points. `ggplotly` uses the `label aesthetic`, so you can ignore the warning. I think it would also occur if you only generate the scatter plot.

Comment: I can't really answer your first question, but apparently if you define a `label` in your `ggplot` function you have to have one everywhere and it tries to add one to your line by looking at a `Species` column in your a, which it does not find. As an alternative to the solution above, you could also move `label = Species` to the geom_point function.

Comment: Thanks. Adding 'label = Species' to the 'geom_point()' layer instead of  'label=NA' in the 'geom_line()' is cleaner as it does not require the label in the 'ggplot()' part.